# resize image in jquery don't applied

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to resize some images when page load.i wrote this codes: but some times applied but sometimes don't applied.
any ideas??

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$( ".img-product" ).each(function( index ) {
        let h=$( this ).height();
        let w=$( this ).width();
        //console.log( index + ": " + w + ":" +h + ":" + $(this).attr('alt'));
        if( h>= 300)
        {
            $(this).removeClass("w-100");
            //console.log( index + ": " + w + ":" +h + ":" + $(this).attr('alt'));
            $(this).css({
                   'width' : 'auto',
                   'margin-right':'auto',
                   'margin-left':'auto'});
                   
                   
        }
         
});
})
```

Comment: Is the DOM really ready? Or are the elements with the `img-product` class added via an async function? In case the latter you need to delay your fix until the DOM is complete.

Comment: Yes sometimes the code run before images get fully loaded .. you can use `setTimeout` to add some seconds then run the code OR you can use [imageLoded Plugin](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Comment: doc ready is fired when the **DOM is ready** - it has nothing to do with when images have loaded, which are loaded after the DOM (or in parallel depending on where they are in the DOM, or immediately if cached).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `load` event directly on the images, so the callback will execute on an image when it's loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".img-product").on("load", function() {
        let h=$(this).height();
        let w=$(this).width();
        //console.log( w + ":" +h + ":" + $(this).attr('alt'));
        if(h >= 300)
        {
            $(this).removeClass("w-100");
            //console.log( w + ":" +h + ":" + $(this).attr('alt'));
            $(this).css({
                   'width' : 'auto',
                   'margin-right':'auto',
                   'margin-left':'auto'});
                   
                   
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 // code here
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//code
}
```